# struct sizeof result not expected

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

I have a a struct defined thusly:

```
typedef struct _CONFIGURATION_DATA {
    BYTE configurationIndicator;
    ULONG32 baudRate;
    BYTE stopBits;
    BYTE parity;
    BYTE wordLength;
    BYTE flowControl;
    BYTE padding;
} CONFIGURATION_DATA;
```

Now, by my reckoning, that struct is 10 bytes long.  However, sizeof reports that it is 16 bytes long?  Anyone know why?

I am compiling using the build tools in the Windows DDK.

Comment: forced alignment of some sort?

Comment: Remember:  The size of a structure may not be equal to the sum of the sizes of its members; implementations are allowed to insert padding between members and after the last members.  <b>ALWAYS</b> access members by name, not by offset as the offset may change between compiler versions and vendors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alignment.

use

`#pragma pack(1)`

`...struct goes here...`

`#pragma pack()`

I would also recommend reordering things, and if necessary padding then with RESERVED bytes,  so that multi-byte integral types will be better aligned. This will make processing faster for tbe CPU, and your code smaller.

Comment: Only do this if you've got a good reason to -- many architectures disallow misaligned accesses (so the compiler will have to use byte loads and saves for safety) and most introduce a performance penalty.

Comment: True. But I'd expect the compiler to generate proper instructions to access misaligned integral types when architecture does not support it. 

This is a common pattern to access binary data in files, communications and other IO. On the contrary, i'd say avoid writing a structure if you do not specify the alignment explicitly, because it will change with compiler version/settings.

Comment: Actually, the reason i need it packed like this is because it gets written to a socket, and the communications spec dicatates a 10-byte message.

Comment: @Pavel -- you might 'expect' the compiler to do something but there is no guarantee that it will! For example the MS VC++ cross-compiler will not automatically generate instructions for misaligned types, you have to explicitly tell it to do so using pointers declared with __unaligned.

Comment: @Pavel: I certainly wouldn't "expect" that. You're just spoiled because you're used to x86 hardware. Writing programs that crash at the slightest provocation is a "common pattern" too.

Comment: @jalf, AAT: by "expect", I mean exactly this: "compiler is the proper abstraction layer where handing alignment misfortune belongs". For instance, tightly packed struct members should be treated by MSVC just as __unaligned. All other compilers should be inserting the bit magic, because in this particular case the compiler can know that pointer may be unaligned.

Comment: BTW, `#pragma pack` is not part of the standard and not necessary supported by all compilers.  A better method is to provide an interface for reading and writing fields to a packed buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Change the order of the elements. Start with the ULONG, followed by the BYTEs. This will improve the struct's alignment in memory.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to padding, because on your platform, an `ULONG32` apparently must be aligned on 4-byte boundaries. Since the start and end of the `struct` apparently also must be aligned, the first and last `BYTE` will be padded with 3 bytes each.

Answer (score 2):

The extra size you are measuring is the padding introduced by the compiler.

Presumably, you are working on a 32 bits system, so you will have 3 bytes of padding between `configurationIndicator` and `baudRate`, and 3 more bytes of padding at the end of the struct.