# Why does 'sizeof' give wrong measurement?

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [struct sizeof result not expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913842/struct-sizeof-result-not-expected)

I have this C++ struct:

```
struct bmp_header {

  //bitmap file header (14 bytes)
  char Sign1,Sign2; //2
  unsigned int File_Size; //4
  unsigned int Reserved_Dword; //4
  unsigned int Data_Offset; //4

  //bitmap info header (16 bytes)
  unsigned int Dib_Info_Size; //4
  unsigned int Image_Width; //4
  unsigned int Image_Height; //4

  unsigned short Planes; //2
  unsigned short Bits; //2  
};
```

It is supposed to be 30 bytes, but 'sizeof(bmp_header)' gives me value 32. What's wrong?

Comment: Struct data alignment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: `s/It is supposed to be 30 bytes/The sum total of each member is 30 bytes/` <-- BIG difference. Break down assumptions when breaking down problems.

Comment: Also please do a search first next time.

Comment: try changing the first to `char Sign[2];`.

Comment: In the end of the day, though, it doesn't really make much difference because, due to padding, if you have an array of `bmp_header` structs or something like that, padding will be included between the elements of the array anyway.

Comment: that's why when i read the bmp header directly from the file to the structure, everything cockups coz of the alignment shift :), but fine now, i read to an byte array then convert to the struct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is because of padding.  If you put the `char`s at the end of the struct, `sizeof` will probably give you 30 bytes.  Integers are generally stored on memory addresses that are multiples of 4.  Therefore, since the chars take up 2 bytes, there are two unused bytes between it and the first unsigned int.  `char`, unlike `int`, is not usually padded.

In general, if space is a big concern, always order elements of `structs` from largest in size to smallest.

Note that padding is NOT always (or usually) the `sizeof(element)`.  It is a **coincidence** that `int` is aligned on 4 bytes and `char` is aligned on 1 byte.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't give a wrong measurement. You need to learn about [alignment and padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

The compiler can add padding in between structure members to respect alignment constraints. That said, it's possible to control padding with compiler specific directives (see [GCC  variable attributes](http://index-g_t_0040code_007bpacked_007d-attribute-2577) or [MSVC++ pragmas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

```
struct bmp_header {

  char Sign1,Sign2; //2
  // padding for 4 byte alignment of int: // 2
  unsigned int File_Size; //4
  unsigned int Reserved_Dword; //4
  unsigned int Data_Offset; //4

  unsigned int Dib_Info_Size; //4
  unsigned int Image_Width; //4
  unsigned int Image_Height; //4

  unsigned short Planes; //2
  unsigned short Bits; //2  
};
```

2+2+4+4+4+4+4+4+2+2 = 32. Looks correct to me. If you expect 30 it means you expect 1 byte padding, as in :

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

struct bmp_header {

  char Sign1,Sign2; //2
  unsigned int File_Size; //4
  unsigned int Reserved_Dword; //4
  unsigned int Data_Offset; //4

  unsigned int Dib_Info_Size; //4
  unsigned int Image_Width; //4
  unsigned int Image_Height; //4

  unsigned short Planes; //2
  unsigned short Bits; //2  
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```