# Access to struct property while looping array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, arduino, platformio

I've occured problem looping through array of structs.

I've got this struct:

```
struct sensor
{
  float data = 0;
  bool status = false;
  Idx idx; //enum
  SensorType type; //enum
};
```

It contains some sensors for my arduino.

So to send data, that I've recieved from them I want to use array of sensors in loop.

This is my array definition:

```
sensor sensors[] = {light, pressure, pressureHpa, temperature, humidity, temperatureOut, humidityOut};
```

Finally, I want to loop through this array and call some methods, but when I try to access any sensor by index I get zero values for all properties.

```
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(sensors) / sizeof(sensor); i++)
  {
    Serial.print("type:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].type);
    Serial.print(" sens.idx:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].idx);
    Serial.print(" sens.data:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].data);
    Serial.print(" sens.status:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].status);
    Serial.println();
  }
```

In this loop I've got output like:

```
type:0 sens.idx:0 sens.data:0.00 sens.status:0
type:0 sens.idx:0 sens.data:0.00 sens.status:0
type:0 sens.idx:0 sens.data:0.00 sens.status:0
type:0 sens.idx:0 sens.data:0.00 sens.status:0
type:0 sens.idx:0 sens.data:0.00 sens.status:0
type:0 sens.idx:0 sens.data:0.00 sens.status:0
type:0 sens.idx:0 sens.data:0.00 sens.status:0
```

But, when I access any of my structs directly like:

```
Serial.print("type:");
Serial.print(pressure.type);
Serial.print(" pressure.idx:");
Serial.print(pressure.idx);
Serial.print(" pressure.data:");
Serial.print(pressure.data);
Serial.print(" sens.status:");
Serial.print(pressure.status);
Serial.println();
```

I get:

```
type:3 pressure.idx:13 pressure.data:0.00 sens.status:1
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Do not count on the value returned by sizeof() for an struct.

Comment: Please post the complete code

Comment: @Gupta Do you mean "for an array"?

Comment: @Gupta I've already checked sizeof() values, they are correct

Comment: Assuming `sensor sensors[] =...` and `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(sensors) / sizeof(sensor); i++)` are in the same scope, calculating the size should work.

Comment: @Suraj https://www.paste.org/100357

Comment: Recommend placing the code in the question (in [mcve] form) . Links rot and get blocked by firewalls, reducing their utility as a data source.

Comment: `sensor sensors[] = {light, ...};` is making copies.  Is `sensor` safely copy-able?

Comment: Ah smurf. That's sort of the problem. You set `light`, and print `sensors[0]`. Because `sensors[0]` is a copy of `light` made before `light `is set, `sensors[0]` contains the default values.

Comment: @Gupta Why not? Do you have some source that says that sizeof() does not work for structs?

Comment: @MaxLanghof https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351654/why-does-sizeof-give-wrong-measurement

Comment: @WillEccles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351654/why-does-sizeof-give-wrong-measurement

Comment: @Gupta You still haven't told us why that is a problem here. `sizeof(someStruct)` gives you exactly the number of bytes that each element of an array of `somStruct` is apart, which is the property that is used here correctly. Please explain what you think is being done wrong.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I did not tell that it is a problem. I just mentioned "Do not count on the value returned by sizeof() for an struct." just as a hint. In addition, on my VS2015 compiler, the sizeof(sensor) returns 16, that is not the EXACT size of the struct.

Comment: @Gupta You seem to misunderstand/have the wrong expectations for what `sizeof` does. `sizeof` returns _by definition_ the size of the struct (the number of bytes occupied by a standalone instance of it). There is no "exact" size other than what `sizeof` returns, because there simply is no other size. You seem to have some idea/expectation that the sum of the struct member sizes is "more exact", but this value is simply irrelevant for the size of a struct. Everything becomes really simple if you accept that instead of considering `sizeof` to be inexact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`light` is defined and left at its default values.

```
sensor sensors[] = {light, pressure, pressureHpa, temperature, humidity, temperatureOut, humidityOut};
```

copies `light` into `sensors[0]`. This means `sensors[0]` contains the same data as `light`, but is not the same thing as `light`. Later when the code assigns values to `light`, `sensors[0]`'s copy is left untouched.

## Option 1

Discard `light` and friends. Add an enumerated type that names the sensors

```
enum sensor_names
{
    LIGHT, // will be 0
    PRESSURE, //will be 1
    ...
    NR_SENSORS // must be last. Used to size the array and for loop terminators
};
```

And make `sensors` a simple array of the correct size

```
sensor sensors[NR_SENSORS];
```

Feel free to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and the [smarter `enum`s of modern C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) if they are available. I'm weak on what is and isn't available to Arduino, so I've stuck to basic C-Style arrays and `enum`s. If you have better tools, use them.

Then access that which was `light` as `sensors[LIGHT];`

## Option 2

Make `sensors` store pointers and change the accessing accordingly.

```
sensor * sensors[] = {&light, &pressure,  .... };
```

I prefer the first option. No duplication and a lower chance of placing an item in the wrong place in the array making a difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array of structs:

```
sensor sensors[] = {light, pressure, pressureHpa, temperature, humidity, temperatureOut, humidityOut};
```

This creates a *copy* of each struct you're using to make the list. You either have to use an array of pointers:

```
sensor* sensors[] = {&light, &pressure, &pressureHpa, &temperature, &humidity, &temperatureOut, &humidityOut};
```

Or you have to create your own class, which stores a reference to them:

```
class SensorArray {
    sensor** arr = nullptr;
    size_t count = 0; 
   public:
    size_t size() const {
        return count; 
    }
    // Default-construct it
    SensorArray() = default;

    // Make a copy of the SensorArray 
    SensorArray(SensorArray const& source)
      : arr(new sensor*[source.size()])
      , count(source.size())
    {
        std::copy_n(source.arr, source.count, arr);
    }

    // Move-construct SensorArray
    SensorArray(SensorArray&& source)
      : arr(source.arr)
      , count(source.count)
    {
        source.arr = nullptr; 
        source.count = 0; 
    }

    template<class T...>
    SensorArray(T&... sensors)
      : arr(new sensor*[] { &sensors... }) // Initialize arr
      , count(sizeof...(sensors))          // Initialize count
    {} // Constructor is empty because we already initialized stuff

    SensorArray& operator=(SensorArray const& source) {
        if(this == &source) return *this;

        SensorArray s = source;
        swap(s);
        return *this; 
    }

    // Copy-and-swap idiom
    // This automatically handles the case of self-assignment
    SensorArray& operator=(SensorArray&& source) {
        SensorArray s = std::move(source);
        swap(s);
        return *this;
    }
    sensor& operator[](int index) const {
        return *arr[index];
    }

    ~SensorArray() {
         delete[] arr;
    }
    void swap(SensorArray& other) {
        std::swap(arr, other.arr);
        std::swap(count, other.count);
    }
};
```

This class will work as intended in your code because it'll store a *reference* to each sensor, rather than a copy:

```
SensorArray sensors { light, pressure, pressureHpa, temperature, humidity, temperatureOut, humidityOut };

  // sensors will update correctly
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sensors.size(); i++)
{
    Serial.print("type:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].type);
    Serial.print(" sens.idx:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].idx);
    Serial.print(" sens.data:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].data);
    Serial.print(" sens.status:");
    Serial.print(sensors[i].status);
    Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: what advantage has the class? the other answer shows how to make things simpler

Comment: The other one requires using an array of pointers. This acts as an array of references, which is what the user originally wanted (and what they wrote their code expecting)

Comment: so OP should create a class as a workaround for unfamiliarity with C(++)?

Comment: OP should create a class that solves their problem. And I've written that class for them.