# Size of a struct in C

Tags: c, memory, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the actual size of a struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983158/what-is-the-actual-size-of-a-struct-in-c)

I wrote the following program in C and I'm a little confused about the size of the struct that the executable prints. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct domi1{
   char x;
   int c;
   char y;
};

struct domi2{
   char x;
   char y;
   int c;
};

main(){

 printf("The size of domi1 is: %d\n", sizeof(struct domi1));
 printf("The size of domi2 is: %d\n\n", sizeof(struct domi2));

 system("pause");
}
```

The program prints 12 as the size of domi1 and 8 as the size of domi2. Why is that? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

because of `Packing and byte alignment`
The general answer is that compilers are free to add padding between members for alignment purpose. or we can say that, You might have a compiler that aligns everything to 8 bytes.
first struct assigned memory as- 4 4 4 
second struct- single 4 for both `char` and 4 for `int`

Comment: Thanks for your response!!quite helped me..

Comment: I don't think this is the complete answer

Comment: Actually memory is aligned according to the sizeof largest datatype

Comment: for actual clarification use "double" in your struct and just check with the different order of declaration sequence you will get it